# Mail not sending after going live in docusign using python quickstart

Tags: docusignapi

I am using python quickstart to set up my app. I have gone live. I have added a new private key and set it up, changed the client id, and user id in the code. Still the mail is not sending. What else do i have to do to move to production?
When i change back the keys and client and user id then it works but only in dev.
Please help

Comment: Which example from the quickstart? And do you get an error? do you see the envelope in your account but just not get the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed all the steps in the [After Go-Live](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/after-go-live/) guide? If so and you still are unable to use your integration in your production account, I would recommend opening a support case with [DocuSign Developer Suppor](https://developers.docusign.com/support/)t because there is not enough information here to effectively point what could be the reason

Comment: I did follow that but what is redirect uri? I just added google.com to test
I get error 
consent required
and when i click the link it says 
The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign

Comment: Redirect Uri is where you will be redirected to when you grant consent. You can add it by opening the integration key under Apps and Keys and add the redirect Uri there. You can continue to use google.com to test if you like